# get index.html file& error 304 as result to get requests that has been sent to the server.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, react-router

I've created nodejs + react application and deployed it to heroku

In the chrome devtools - get request that sent to the backend **after adding this code to server.js** i get the index.html as result - and error 304.

```
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

**Before I added this line**, the application did the get requests,
but when the user want to get directly to some page in the app, for example: "https://appname.herokuapp.com/path/**username**". 
he gets this error : `Cannot GET /path/username`

but when he press link button `<a href = "/path/username">User Name</a>` from home page, he will get to the requested page, after refresh he will get the error again - the path hasn’t changed.

**when i check the get route in POSTMAN i get back the index.html file..**

Comment: Please add one other backend route. And is this the first route of your application?

Comment: hey, here is the route that gets this 304 error : const trackerRoute = require('./api/tracker/tracker.routes');
app.use('/api/tracker', trackerRoute); ( i dont have more routes in the backend)  in this trackerRouter this is the route - router.get('/', getAllCountries);... and yeah - "https://appname.herokuapp.com/" is the home path and "https://appname.herokuapp.com/path/username" is a path to user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the order of your routes is wrong. For a single page applicaiton, all the routes should be BEFORE the `*` route. So basically the `*` should be lowest in the application.

So an example would be:

```
// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/build')));

// THIS IS YOU API ENDPOINT
app.get('/api/getList', (req,res) => {
    var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    res.json(list);
});

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Single Page Applications are tricky that way. Let me explain why it's happening and why you need to redirect to **"*"** route for that matter.

When you load the homepage, for example to www.mysite.com request is sent to the server and it loads **index.html** that exist on the root directory i.e. **www.mysite.com/**.

But when you request **www.mysite.com/username** it makes requests to server first and will look for **index.html** in username directory which doesn't exist.

The problem is that routing in react is taking place on the client side i.e. your browser. So you when you click from the link it navigates perfectly as index.html has already loaded and react router is doing the magic, but when you do that on server it won't be able to locate the index.html unless it's the root directory.